# Is it possible to make a linked chekbox?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I mean as soon as you click the checkbox to direct you to a link? I am currently making a switch type button and wondering if i can link someone to a webpage as soon as they turn the switch.

Comment: Avoid no standard behavior. It can confuse user or it might not works as intended on some platform.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is certainly possible with event listeners.

However, it would be *very* bad UX, as no-one expects clicking on a checkbox to do anything other than toggle the checkbox and possibly display a message related to the checkbox. It's best to stick with a normal link.

Comment: @gcambell Thank you man i understand your point but i am actually making a switch that when turned(selected) you skip the page intro.

Comment: @AngeloNuho In that case it should be a link.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use `jquery`. Its a common library based on `javascript` and the demo is simple and easy to read.  You can check it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nt74b3w0/).

the html

```
<label>Checkbox linked<label/><input type="checkbox" id="checkId"/>
```

jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#checkId").click(function(){
        //this option open a new tab
        window.open("http://www.facebook.com");
        //this option open in te current tab
        window.location = "http://www.facebook.com";
    });
});
```

Comment: How does that do a redirect?

Comment: i make a modification to show how to redirect

Answer (score -1):

You can use a JavaScript onclick event on the checkbox and redirect them by using window.location as seen here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp

Answer (score -2):

```html
<a onclick='window.location="https://google.com"'>
  <label>
    Click me
    <input type='checkbox'/>
  </label>
</a>
```

Comment: This is not valid HTML.

Comment: You can't have `<input>` inside `<a>`.

Comment: @Barmar You can have an `input` inside an `a`... if it's set to `type="hidden"` :P